# Git log main branch on top

Tags: git

When running `git log --all --online --graph` the output i.e. is as following:

```
* a9815e5 (HEAD -> feat) f2
* efe97d6 f1
| * 797b857 (master) m1
|/
* 5074e60 c1
```

And this doesnt matter if I am on feat or on master.

Right now this command always puts the branch with the most recent commit on the left. If adding another commit on master it looks like this and doesnt show the correct timeline anymore. Note m1 moved up:

```
* 158dd8f (HEAD -> master) m2
* 797b857 m1
| * a9815e5 (feat) f2
| * efe97d6 f1
|/
* 5074e60 c1
```

**Is there a way to rather show the master branch as the main one (on the left)?**

```
   * a9815e5 (HEAD -> feat) f2
   * efe97d6 f1
* 797b857 (master) m1
|/
* 5074e60 c1
```

Or with second commit

```
* 158dd8f (HEAD -> master) m2
|  * a9815e5 (HEAD -> feat) f2
|  * efe97d6 f1
* 797b857 (master) m1
|/
* 5074e60 c1
```

P.S. just thinking, typing this makes me realize that the layout is a bit confusing as well.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in command line.